# apply Function one raw input ,many raws output

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply, tapply

I have a table like this:

```
customer   ID    startdate   enddate
11         22   2015-01-01  2015-03-01
11         55   2018-04-03  2018-06-16
22         33   2017-02-01  2017-04-01
```

And This is the output I want:

```
   customer    Id  YearMonth
    11         22   201501
    11         22   201502
    11         22   201503
    11         55   201804
    11         55   201805
    11         55   201806
    22         33   201702
    22         33   201703
    22         33   201704
    22         33   201505
```

I've Started writing this function:

```
datseq<-function(t1,t2) {
seq(as.Data(t1), as.Date(t2), by="month")
}
```

My Questions are:

a. How can I correct the function to return me YYYYMM format?

b. How can I implemnt this function on the dataframe in order that each customer and id will get the appropriate list of months? The output should be a dataframe.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`, group by the sequence of rows, create a sequence from the 'startdate' to 'enddate', specifying the `by` as monthly and `format` the `Date` class to return the expected format (`"%Y%m"`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(customer = customer[1], Id = ID[1], 
 YearMonth = format(seq(startdate, enddate, by = '1 month'), "%Y%m")),
      by = 1:nrow(df1)]
```

---

This can also be done with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(YearMonth = map2(startdate, enddate, 
       ~ seq(.x, .y, by = "1 month") %>%
              format(., format = "%Y%m"))) %>% 
  select(-startdate, enddate) %>% 
  unnest
```

---

If we need a `base R`, option, then `Map` can be used

```
lst <- Map(function(x, y) seq(x, y, by = '1 month'), df1$startdate, df1$enddate)
```

Replicate the rows of the dataset by the `lengths` of the `list`, and create a column 'YearMonth' by concatenating the `list` elements and then getting the expected `format`

```
data.frame(df1[rep(1:nrow(df1), lengths(lst)), 1:2], 
           YearMonth = format(do.call(c, lst), "%Y%m"))
```

Comment: And without data.table?